# three.js importing GLTF error (Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON)

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

trying to import my first `.gltf` model in three.js with the parcel when greeted with a black screen and this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at GLTFLoader.parse (GLTFLoader.js:315:21)
    at Object.onLoad (GLTFLoader.js:205:11)
    at three.module.js:39951:38
```

my imports

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { PerspectiveCamera } from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'
import { DRACOLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js'
```

```
let loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load( './js/assets/brain.gltf', function ( gltf )
{
  brain = gltf.scene;
  brain.scale.set(2, 2, 2);
  brain.position.y = 4;
  scene.add(brain);
} );
```

HTML

```
  <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
  <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "three": "../build/three.module.js",
        "three/addons/": "./jsm/"
      }
    }
  </script>
  <script type="module" src="./js/index.js" defer></script>
</body>
```

[my path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcX0p.png)
the path to asset seems correct, right?

I have attempted different GLTFs, tried GLB files, and tried changing up my path but receive the same error

Comment: That error is trying to tell you that when accessing `./js/assets/brain.gltf`, your server is returning an HTML page, instead of the actual `.gltf` file. (HTML pages start with `<!DOCTYPE`) Are you sure the file exists at that address? What happens when you navigate your browser there?

Comment: @Marquizzo upon navigating nothing happens console logs same error

Comment: Marquizzo is saying enter the **fully qualified** path to `./js/assets/brain.gltf` into your browser. (It must be fully-qualified because your browser can't understand the relative path.) I'm guessing you'll get an HTML page with an HTTP error (404, 503, etc.).

Comment: @TheJim01 upon doing that i get same result. tried to use an OBJ with the OBJ loader also but to no avail. with OBJ it will state `THREE.OBJLoader: Unexpected line: "<!DOCTYPE html>"` and so forth with the rest of my HTML

Comment: If a request to `http://yoursite/js/assets/brain.gltf` is responding with the HTML from YOUR `index.html`, then your server is not configured correctly. Ensure that your server is responding with the file data (it should trigger a download when you navigate to the URL for the gltf file), then everything should work as expected.

Comment: @TheJim01 how would i go about that?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is a completely different topic. I recommend testing your server by trying to fetch the file directly, gather information about your findings, and asking a new question with appropriate tags like the name of the server you're using, and the type of file. Include all the verification steps you've done, so people have a place to start helping.

Comment: @TheJim01 i configured my server with parcel and have solved issue. needed to add my .parcelrc file and added a data folder to store my file. built using `npx parcel index.html data/**/*`

Comment: Hey @Noah Keith, I'm getting the same error on my three js project. Can you please specify what is needed in the .parcelrc file?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: it was caused by an incorrect path.

Do not use a relative path.

You should put the glb file in your public folder，and only write the glb file name when using GLTFLoader.

For example:

```
loader.load('a.glb', (obj) => {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Even i had the same issue Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

by adding the .glb folder in the public folder in react fixed my issue
i used

```bash
npx GLTFjsx <name.glb>
```

created a react component

by using useGLTF hook from @react-three/drei i loaded the model

hope this fixes the issue
thank you